# Seg Fault when freeing unrelated data

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm creating a table with linked lists where the data is duplicated when it is passed to the insertion methods. 
To test this, I create an array with the values that I will insert and then insert them into the table. When I free the array and then free the table, I receive a SEG FAULT error. As such, I have concluded that the pointers in both structures must be pointing to the same memory region. However, as I duplicate the data, I cannot see where the problem could be coming from...

Here is the code for the test:

```
for(i=0; i<1024; i++) {
    key[i] = (char*)malloc(16*sizeof(char));
    sprintf(key[i],"a/key/b-%d",i);
    data[i] = data_create2(strlen(key[i])+1,strdup(key[i]));

    table_put(table,key[i],data[i]);
}

assert(table_size(table) == 1024);
result = (table_size(table) == 1024);

for(i=0; i<1024; i++) {
    d = table_get(table,key[i]);

    assert(d->datasize == data[i]->datasize);
    assert(memcmp(d->data,data[i]->data,d->datasize) == 0);
    assert(d->data != data[i]->data);

    result = result && (d->datasize == data[i]->datasize && 
                       memcmp(d->data,data[i]->data,d->datasize) == 0 &&
                       d->data != data[i]->data);
    data_destroy(d);
}

for(i=0; i<1024; i++) {
    free(key[i]);
    //data_destroy(data[i]);
}

table_destroy(table);
```

When I uncomment that data_destroy(data[i]) line, the program gives the Seg Fault.

The code for the table_put:

```
int table_put(struct table_t *table, char * key, struct data_t *value) {


if(table == NULL || key == NULL || value == NULL) return -1;



struct entry_t *new_pair = entry_create(key, value);



int i = key_hash(key, table->size);

int l = 0;
if (list_get(table->list[i], new_pair->key) == NULL) {
    l = 1;
}   

if(list_add(table->list[i], new_pair)==-1){

    entry_destroy(new_pair);
    return -1;
} 
table -> length = table -> length + l;

return 0;

}
```

The code for: entry_create, where I duplicate the data:

```
struct entry_t *entry_create(char *key, struct data_t *data){
if(data == NULL || key == NULL){
    return NULL;
}
struct entry_t *entry = (struct entry_t *) malloc(sizeof(struct entry_t));
if(entry == NULL){
    return NULL;
}
entry->key = (char*) malloc(sizeof(strlen(key))+1);

memcpy(entry->key,key,strlen(key)+1);


entry->value = data_dup(data);


//free(key);
data_destroy(data);
return entry;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [**Minimal**, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: A possible hint about your problem though: How many times do you call `data_destroy` with the same pointer? Try printing out the pointer in your `data_destroy` function and count.

Comment: have you tried running this under valgrind?

Comment: `data_destroy` doesn't assign `NULL` to the pointer after it frees the memory, does it? :) `free(NULL)` won't do any harm even if programmer will fail to realize that he does it twice, on the other hand, `free(???)` could either set your computer on file, delete all your files, or send "lol gay" to your grandma, which one you prefer is on you. You should be happy when you segfault because it could not (pointer points to some place in your program instead of memory that doesn't belong to it), and then you can only pray that it won't do anything bad. TL;DR always `free(ptr); *ptr = NULL;`

Answer (score 0):

segfaults on free are usually double free's means that you've tried to free something that's already been free'd . or  when you try to free pointer with out any malloc.
is there any malloc on data_create2 function ?

if there is not it is the case you are trying to free data array members that where never malloc'd

Comment: When you free and get a segfault, it means that you tried to free memory that wasn't even yours to begin with (e.g. you still have a pointer to a page that was freed and sent back to free memory pool, and when you try to free what's not yours, OS takes your hand and shows you the door), you could try to free somewhere in your own process space and then it won't segfault, but won't be very pleasant either. In best case your program will just crash unexpectedly, in worst... Anything can happen.